# Matrix indexing with lapply and seq_along

Tags: r, lapply

`lapply` does not work as intended. I got the following function:

```
testing <- function(x){
     x <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[[i]][,2] <- c(88,88,88))
     return(x)
}
```

and the list of test matrices:

```
xl <- list(matrix(1:9,3,3),matrix(2:10,3,3))
```

the output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 88 88 88

[[2]]
[1] 88 88 88
```

Why is this the case? I would expect the second columns to be substituted with 88 each, but not the matrices to be replaced by vectors of 88s. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @Frank thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
testing <- function(x){
       lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {x[[i]][,2] <- 88
                                     x[[i]]})}
testing(list)
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1   88    7
#[2,]    2   88    8
#[3,]    3   88    9

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2   88    8
#[2,]    3   88    9
#[3,]    4   88   10
```

Or we loop through the `list`, change the 2nd column to 88 and return the list element.

```
 lapply(list, function(x) {x[,2] <- 88; x})
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can use a `for` loop and assign the 2nd column of each `list` element as 88.

```
for (j in seq_along(list)) list[[j]][, 2] <- 88
```

Comment: Ok so the major change seems to be the addition of `x[[i]]` at the end, correct?

Comment: @EDC The major change is that we need to return `x[[i]]`

Comment: `for (j in seq_along(x)) x[[j]][, 2] <- 88` and `return(x)` is another alternative, closer to the OP's initial idea maybe.

Comment: @akrun I see, so one last thing: It seems that `lapply` cannot be used to change the columns of a list of matrices, but a for loop must be used instead. Is this the right conclusion? Because that's what I tried to achieve here.

Comment: @EDC If you look at the 2nd solution, we are changing the matrix column using `lapply`.  The reason `for` loop is used is it doesn't need to return x as in `lapply`

Comment: @akrun thanks I see. I was missing to return the changed list elements (new matrices). However the output generated by R from my (originally posted) function still does not seem logical to me...

Comment: @EDC The return value of `xl[[1]][,2] <- 88` is `88`. You can see this by wrapping in parentheses and assigning the result somewhere, like `z <- (xl[[1]][,2] <- 88)`. `lapply` gives the return value for every evaluation of the function.

Comment: @Frank ok I see. Never seen a structure like that before. Thanks for all the comments!